# Does macOS BigSur blocks network for non signed application?

Tags: security, networking, macos-big-sur

I am taking part to the development of Scilab ([www.scilab.org](http://www.scilab.org)) on macOS and I noticed that all network requests from the software (using shell commands) fail with status = 48 (client hostname could not be found). All the commands work fine when typed directly on the terminal. I didn't find which app or service has to be added in the Security & privacy control panel. Does anybody did encounter a similar problem and found a solution ?

S.